# How to add sticky side bar on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add sticky side-bar on my WordPress website. I tried it many times through the material available on the different website, but never succeeded.

I don't want to use WordPress plugins as most of such plugins not updated for many years.

Comment: Got any code for us?

Answer (score 0):

You can do by adding dynamic class by using jquery

This is sample code that I used on my one of the sites on scroll dynamic class add.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

                if (scroll > 100) { // This is scroll height you can change as per your need

                    $(".mobile_menu").addClass("sticky-sidebar"); // sticky-header is class which will add and mobile_menu is the base class where sticky-header will be added.

                } else {

                    $(".mobile_menu").removeClass("sticky-sidebar");

                }

            });
```

[image]

[image]

In last need to add css like position: fixed; and z-index:9999;

Comment: Hi, Thank for prompt reply. Can you tell where to put these codes? I placed the jQuery on additional CSS and div on the sidebar. But still not working

Comment: if you add this code in wordpress then you can add in footer.php or by calling new js file in header or footer